# Relationship with same entity - ER Diagrams

Tags: entity-relationship, er-diagram

I'm developing a ER model and i have a trouble.

I have a entity called client and it pay for another client (Same entity)

It's something like this:

client(one,many) --- PAY-->(relationship) --- (one,many)client

that this right?

I thank those who help me.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english, i'm still learning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

*client(one,many) --- PAYS FOR-->(relationship) --- (one,many)client*

is correct.

These relationships between the entities are called Recursive Relationships. It is similar to a manager paying an employee, as the manager is also an employee. Employee == Client in your case.

Do go through this site to get a detailed knowledge about relationships. http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SoftDevRDS02CD/page_49.htm

Comment: The link that you've given is dead.